# How can I force blender to use texture from a modified imported object?

Tags: edit-mode

[ADDED LATER]
In desperation I RENAMED the offending texture files and rebuilt everything which fixed the problem. Still it would be interesting to find out why removing an imported object and replacing with an imported rebuilt object with different sized texture files still resulted in the exported texture file being the same as the original.

I imported a glTF object (wooden bench) into an existing Blender 'project' saved (the Blender file) and exported all to an extended glTF. I then discovered that one of the textures was not 'square' ie the dimensions were not to the power of 4 and so I used my image editor to resize the texture file for the imported object (wooden bench) and saved. I then started Blender with a 'black canvas' imported the glTF (with the resized texture file) and exported as glTF so that I would have a 3D object of the wooden bench with correct texture image to be used in other projects. I checked the dimensions of the output texture file and they were correct.
I then opened my original Blender project, removed the old object (wooden bench) and imported the modified wooden bench and exported as glTF. The output texture files are the OLD ones ie the texture file with the incorrect dimensions. Somehow Blender is picking up the texture file from elsewhere not the imported object.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Please do not add "solved" as part of the title. Mark the answer that 
helped you as accepted instead (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBQh7.png). 
Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works. Read also: 
[what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Please remember not to put an answer in your question. Instead, at least write the answer as an answer. 

Comment: Thanks guys. I am learning more about how this web site/forum works which is VERY different from any other forum I have ever used. I added the answer to my question BEFORE I noticed (at the bottom) that I could 'answer my question.' I added SOLVED as that is the method in many other forums (so that readers can see at a glance that they don't need to add anything).

Answer (score 0):

In desperation I RENAMED the offending texture files and rebuilt everything which fixed the problem. AND this model is the ONLY model with the textures so it wasn't a problem with another model having the same textures. Still it would be interesting to find out why removing an imported object and replacing with an imported rebuilt object with different sized texture files still resulted in the exported texture file being the same as the original.